# Call mouse hover if the user cursor is over my element for a few second

Tags: jquery, events

I have an element and i want do something on mouse hover event!
I tried this:

```
$("#myElement").hover(
function () { // in 
    ...
},
function () { // out
    ...
});
```

But it should not run immediately.
I want fire hover event after a few seconds.
how can i implement this?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? You can search for something like `setTimeout` in order to delay the function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll be waiting `setTimeout()`

You should really be searching a little more before posting this question.

```
(function() {

    var time = 1000,
        timer;

    function handlerIn() {
        clearTimeout(timer);
    }
    function handlerOut() {
        timer = setTimeout(function() {
            $('.target').fadeOut(3000);
        }, time);
    }

    $("#myElement").hover(handlerIn, handlerOut);

}());
```

Whats happening here is simple, on hoverin start the timer which is set to `1000`, but when you hover out it cancels `clearTimeout()` the timer that you just set

Comment: excuse me! It's true... tanks.